# I want to display a result of `ADSTech` with the help of LIKE statement

Tags: mysql, database

I want to display a result of `ADSTech` with the help of LIKE statement

```
SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE `name` LIKE '%ADS Technology%'
```

but this query is not executing perfectly then my question is, which query is the best for this result if I search like this?

[image]

Here is my database screenshot also

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Levenshtein Distance Algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), There is alot of implementations out there for this algorithm in mysql like this one:

- [Levenshtein distance as User Defined Function](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552).